# How can I "bridge" React DOM gap

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-dom

I am writing my first React app using Next.js and I have encountered a difficulty. I have a map in my page. Map is pretty complex element and I need to insert react components into it. So the situation is:

```
<body>
  <SomeContext.Provider value={...}>
    <React>
      <Dom>
        <TheMap />
      </Dom>
    </React>
  </SomeContext.Provider>
</body>
```

The Map is just a wrapper element and the map is rendered into it using `useRef()`. But I need to append something into the Map DOM. The map has an API that needs native `HTMLElement`. So I made something like:

```
function mkElementWithComponent(someReactComponent) {
  const elm = document.createElement("div");
  ReactDOM.render(<someReactComponent />, elm);
  return elm;
}
```

This seemed to work until I've discovered, that the component rendered this way can not read the SomeContext value. It reads only the default value. This is a problem. How to solve this? Is there a way how to pass the gap in React DOM? What can I pass to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a React portal instead. The signature and usage is nearly identical to that of `ReactDOM.render`. The portal allows you to render components elsewhere in the DOM but have them behave as though they were just normal children components.

[Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)

> #### Usage
>
> Normally, when you return an element from a component’s render method,
> it’s mounted into the DOM as a child of the nearest parent node:
>
> ```
> render() {
>   // React mounts a new div and renders the children into it
>   return (
>     <div>
>       {this.props.children}
>     </div>
>   );
> }
> ```
>
> However, sometimes it’s useful to insert a child into a different
> location in the DOM:
>
> ```
> render() {
>   // React does *not* create a new div. It renders the children into `domNode`.
>   // `domNode` is any valid DOM node, regardless of its location in the DOM.
>   return ReactDOM.createPortal(
>     this.props.children,
>     domNode
>   );
> }
> ```

Update to your code:

```
function mkElementWithComponent(someReactComponent) {
  const elm = document.createElement("div");
  ReactDOM.createPortal(<someReactComponent />, elm);
  return elm;
}
```